# iText7 - Extract column text header from table (C#)

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

[image]

Is there a technique for keeping the column text grouped? Looked at PdfObjects, nothing there. It's such a great library, but struggling with the loose text. Thanks

[UPDATED]

```
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC));

for (int i=1; i<=pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
{
    LocationTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
    PdfCanvasProcessor parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(strategy);

    PdfPage pg = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);
    parser.ProcessPageContent(pg);

    string content = strategy.GetResultantText();
    pages.Add(content);
}
```

[UPDATE - Results using SimpleTextExtractionStrategy - header text grouped]

```
Pre-Crash Data (Most Recent Event - table 3 of 4)
(the most recent sampled values are recorded prior to the event)
Time
Stamp
(sec)
PRNDL
Status
Reverse
Gear
(Manual
Only)
Tire
Pressure
Monitor
Indicator
Lamp
Tire
Pressure
Status,
LF
Tire
Pressure
Status,
RF
Tire
Pressure
Status,
LR
Tire
Pressure
Status,
RR
-5.0 Drive No Off Normal Normal Normal Normal
```

Comment: Which text extraction strategy do you use?

Comment: According to your code you use the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`. Have you also tried the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy`?

Comment: I have not. I'll give it a shot. Thx

Comment: Much better. The header text is grouped now. Wish they could throw in a delimiter character. I'll post the results above. Thanks mkl!!

Comment: A bit of background: these two strategy classes define the ways iText can extract text out of the box; either it takes the text simply in the order in which it is drawn ("simple" strategy) or it sorts it top-to-bottom, left-to-right ("location" strategy). One can create one's own strategies here which can help for special requirements.

Comment: You may want to try using iText pdf2Data add-on (https://pdf2data.online) to extract structured data from PDF